# Mux middleware without handler

Tags: go, mux

I'm building an application using the Micro Service Architecture.
On the gateway, I do want to route requests to the correct endpoints.

But, the endpoint are now known at runtime and needs to be configured in the DB.

Below if the code to get the router.

```
func getRouter() *mux.Router {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    r.Use(dynamicRouteMiddleware)

    return r
}
```

The middleware itself is this:

```
func dynamicRouteMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Error")
    })
}
```

However, the "Error" is never printed.
It's only printed when I put a handler for '/'

How can I create middleware without handlers?

Comment: Why would you need middleware without a handler? I think you are confusing the terms, and it sounds like you want this to be a handler itself instead of middleware.

Comment: That seems a good comment :-) If you set that as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: Can you describe what `dynamicRouteMiddleware` is meant to do [rather than the abstract example] - ?

If you haven't added a route to your `*mux.Router`, nothing will match, and middleware isn't called without a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called "middleware" because it's supposed to put your `Handler` in the "middle". It receives the input before your `Handler`, and receives the output of your `Handler`.

Inherently, to have your middleware work, you are required to have at least one Handler. Preferably you may just use this functionality that you need in the Handler rather than middleware.

Answer (score 1):

On the middleware, you need call the `next` handler so all incoming requests will proceed to the destination route.

```
func dynamicRouteMiddleware(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        fmt.Println("Error")
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r) // <------- this one
    })
}
```

You can register any routes as you want, but in the very end make sure the `r` object used as handler of `/` route.

```
r.HandleFunc("/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("test"))
})

r.HandleFunc("/test/12", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("test 12"))
})

r.HandleFunc("/about-us", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("about us"))
})

http.Handle("/", r)
http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
```

When  you access `/test`, `/test/12`, or `/about-us`; the `Error` will still be printed.

Previously it's not printed because you don't proceed to the next handler. The code `next.ServeHTTP(w, r)` is mandatory in your case.